# Mock custom global window variable for individual tests with Jest

Tags: javascript, reactjs, unit-testing, jestjs, react-testing-library

I'm trying to mock a custom global window variable for an individual test. [Here's a sandbox to the test](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-testing-library-playground-forked-e17f6r?file=/src/MyComponent.test.js) that demonstrates the issue.

I have a React component `MyComponent.tsx` that references a global window variable from `index.html` (from the server).

```
// index.html
<script>
 var globalVars = {
   myVar: "value"
 };
</script>
```

```
// MyComponent.tsx
function MyComponent() {
 const { myWindowVar } = constants;
   return <h1>{myWindowVar}</h1>;
}
```

```
// constants.ts
const constants = {
  myWindowVar: window?.globalVars?.myVar
};
```

I've tried a few methods to mock this variable but it doesn't seem to be applied before `MyComponent` is rendered and the test fails.

```
// MyComponent.test.js
test("Test mocked window variable", () => {
  // 1. trying to mock the global/window object directly doesn't work
  // global.globalVars = { myVar: "mocked value" };

  // 2. also does not work
  // Object.defineProperty(window, "globalVars", {
  //   value: { myVar: "mocked value" },
  //   writable: true
  // });

  // 3. spying on the window object and updating with new
  // variable doesn't work either
  const originalWindow = { ...window };
  const windowSpy = jest.spyOn(global, "window", "get");
  windowSpy.mockImplementation(() => ({
    ...originalWindow,
    globalVars: { myVar: "mocked value" }
  }));

  render(<MyComponent />);

  expect(screen.getByText("mocked value")).toBeInTheDocument();

  windowSpy.mockRestore();
});
```

Is this possible? How can I mock this custom window variable for individual tests with Jest before the component is rendered?